# Python; print filename and header

Tags: python

I have files (fasta files with a sequence) that look like this:

**File1.fasta**

```
>1
GTCTTCCGGCGAGCGGGCTTTTCACCCGCTTTATCGTTACTTATGTCAGCATTCGCACTT
CTGATACCTCCAGCAACCCTCACAGGCCACCTTCGCAGGCTTACAGAACGCTCCCCTACC
CAACAACGCATAAACGTCGCTGCCGCAGCTTCGGTGCATGGTTTAGCCCCGTTACATCTT
CCGCGCAGGCCGACTCGACCAGTGAGCTATTACGCTTTCTTTAAATGATGGCTGCTTCTA
AGCCAACATCCTGGCTGTCTGG
>2
AAAGAAAGCGTAATAGCTCACTGGTCGAGTCGGCCTGCGCGGAAGATGTAACGGGGCTAA
ACCATGCACCGAAGCTGCGGCAGCGACACTCAGGTGTTGTTGGGTAGGGGAGCGTTCTGT
AAGCCTGTGAAGGTGGCCTGTGAGGGTTGCTGGAGGTATCAGAAGTGCGAATGCTGACAT
AAGTAACGATAAAGCGGGTGAAAAGCCCGCTCGCCGGAAGACCAAGGGTTCCTGTCCAAC
GTTAATCGGGGCAGG
```

**File2.fasta**

```
>1
CAACAACGCATAAACGTCGCTGCCGCAGCTTCGGTGCATGGTTTAGCCCCGTTACATCTT
>2
CCGCGCAGGCCGACTCGACCAGTGAGCTATTACGCTTTCTTTAAATGATGGCTGCTTCTA
```

With my script, I count all the 5-mers in these files. My code is as follows:

```
import operator
import glob

def printSeq(name, seq):
    kmers = {}
    k = 5
    for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
       kmer = seq[i:i+k]
       if kmer in kmers:
          kmers[kmer] += 1
       else:
          kmers[kmer] = 1

    for kmer, count in kmers.items():
       print (kmer + "\t" + str(count))

    sortedKmer = sorted(kmers.items(), reverse=True)

    for item in sortedKmer:
       print (item[0] + "\t" + str(item[1]))


for name in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        seq = ""
        key = ""
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith(">"):
                if key and seq:
                    printSeq(key, seq)
                key = line[1:].strip()
                seq = ""
            else:
                seq += line.strip()
        printSeq(key, seq)
```

The output is now the 5-mer followed with the count.

I want to adjust my output so that for each output line I get the filename followed by the header and than the count, like this:

```
File1 1 GTCTT 1
File1 1 TCTTC 1
File1 1 CTTCC 1
....
File2 2 TTCTA 1
```

How can I achieve that?

***Additional question***
I want to add the reverse complement sequence of the data and count that together with the previous data. My code to get the reverse complement is as follows

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for fasta_file in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
        reverse_complement = ">" + record.id + "\n" + record.seq.reverse_complement()
```

So the "reverse_complement" of file one, header >1 has to be counted together with the previous one etc. How can I include this data to my previous files and count together?

My reverse_complement data is

File1.fasta (reverse_complement)

```
>1
CCAGACAGCCAGGATGTTGGCTTAGAAGCAGCCATCATTTAAAGAAAGCGTAATAGCTCACTGGTCGAGTCGGCCTGCGCGGAAGATGTAACGGGGCTAAACCATGCACCGAAGCTGCGGCAGCGACGTTTATGCGTTGTTGGGTAGGGGAGCGTTCTGTAAGCCTGCGAAGGTGGCCTGTGAGGGTTGCTGGAGGTATCAGAAGTGCGAATGCTGACATAAGTAACGATAAAGCGGGTGAAAAGCCCGCTCGCCGGAAGAC
>2
CCTGCCCCGATTAACGTTGGACAGGAACCCTTGGTCTTCCGGCGAGCGGGCTTTTCACCCGCTTTATCGTTACTTATGTCAGCATTCGCACTTCTGATACCTCCAGCAACCCTCACAGGCCACCTTCACAGGCTTACAGAACGCTCCCCTACCCAACAACACCTGAGTGTCGCTGCCGCAGCTTCGGTGCATGGTTTAGCCCCGTTACATCTTCCGCGCAGGCCGACTCGACCAGTGAGCTATTACGCTTTCTTT
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: I would say it is: "*I want to adjust my output that for each output line, first the filename is printed, followed by the header and than the count, like this*" - See his last line of text. You might append: 'How can I achive that?'

Comment: My apologies, you are right, I edit the text with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be done using a `Counter()` as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
import glob

for fasta_file in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fasta_file))[0]

    with open(fasta_file) as f_fasta:
        for k, g in groupby(f_fasta, lambda x: x.startswith('>')):
            if k:
                sequence = next(g).strip('>\n')
            else:
                d = list(''.join(line.strip() for line in g))
                counts = Counter()

                while len(d) >= 5:
                    five_mer = '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4])
                    counts[five_mer] += 1
                    del d[0]

                for five_mer, count in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
                    print "{} {} {} {}".format(basename, sequence, five_mer, count)
```

This would give you output with the largest counts first and then alphabetically:

```
File1 1 CAGGC 3
File1 1 CGCAG 3
File1 1 GCTTT 3
File1 1 AACGC 2
File1 1 ACATC 2
File1 1 ACGCT 2
File1 1 AGGCC 2
```

It uses Python's [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to read groups of lines together. It either reads a single sequence line or a list of five mer lines. `k` is the result of the `startswith()` call. So when `k` is `False`, take all the lines returned, remove the newline from each and then join them together to make a single line of characters.

It then reads the first 5 characters from the list, joins them back together and adds them as a key to a `Counter()`. It then removes the first character from the list and repeats until there are less than 5 characters remaining.

For just alphabetical ordering:

```
for five_mer, count in sorted(counts.items()):
```

A `Counter()` works the same way as a dictionary, so `.items()` would give a list of key value pairs. These are sorted before being displayed.

Comment: The output looks the way I want, however, I want to count the amount of 5-mers in my files; how many ACCCG are in File 1.1, how many ACTTA are in File 1.1 etc. This script gives me which 5-mers I have, but does not count how many.

Comment: It counts 5-mers per line. It can easily count per file, or for all files. What do you need?

Comment: I see, but what I want is that it not count per line, but for all the lines from ">1" to the next ">2". I have edit a larger example of my files to the question, hope that you can help me. The script works great for the lines!

Comment: It now works for the multple lines. How do you want the output sorted? Alphabetically, or by largest count first then alphabetically?

Comment: Works great!  I am adding the data to a pandas dataframe, so no need to sort the output alphabetically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have an editional question. I have to add more data and count that together with the previous data. Can you please take a look? I have edited the next question to the previous one.

Comment: I don't currently have Biopython installed, you might get a quicker reply if you post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You change the signature of

```
def printSeq(name, seq)
```

to

```
def printSeq(file, header, name, seq):
```

incorporate the new variables in the `print` statements.
e.g.

```
print (item[0] + "\t" + str(item[1]))
v
print (file + "\t" + header + "\t" + item[0] + "\t" + str(item[1]))
```

Then, in your loop you pass the information to this function.

You have the file name available in the loop, stored in the variable `name`

You parse the header in the lines where you detect it, and store it in a variable for later use. The later use is when you call the `printSeq`-function

Comment: *incorporate the new variables in the print statements* which are ~12 and ~17 of your function `printSeq`.